# Tailoring AutoCompleteTextView to fit my needs?

Tags: android, android-layout, autocompletetextview

**What I want**

1. A simple EditText. User should be able to enter text at any point of time.
2. onClick of this EditText, a popup should appear anchored to the EditText.
3. onClick of this EditText, if popup is already being shown, then dismiss the popup.
4. This popup will contain a list of items (that i decide and no filtering) on clicking of which the EditText will be filled with the clicked item.
5. When I start typing, the popup should go away.
6. I should be able to set the animation of the drop down list.

**What were my options**

Obviously, AutoCompleteTextView. Worked great after customizing AutoCompleteTextView. But there were two problems?

I was able to accomplish points 1, 2, 4 and 5. How do I get around this number 3 and number 5?

**Since nothing worked...**

I thought I can just put a edit text and show a popup window. :)

**But that fails utterly...**

I just tried to do the simple way. I added a EditText. And then I created a class of PopupWindow and inflated a listview in it. Then I anchored it to my EditText. Now the problem starts again -

1. I click on the EditText. The popup appears. Takes all the focus and the keyboard goes away. Definitely not what I want. So i made the popup window not focusable.
2. And now I click on the EditText, the popup appears. Doesn't take the focus. So keyboard stays to take input. Just perfect like I want. But when I click a list item in the ListView, it doesn't do anything. Why? It is not focusable!

So what do i do now? Which way do I go?

Answer (score 0):

For 3. you can create an onFocusChange listener, or and onClickListener and explicitly call `_autoCompleteView.dismissDropDown();`. You can use `isPopupShowing()` to see if it is already showing and manually dismiss it in that case.

For 5. you just do the same thing but you do `_autoCompleteView.registerDataSetObserver` and put that logic in the `onChanged()` event or possibly in the `addTextChangedListener`on your autoCompleteTextView.

I am not entirely sure if this is the functionality you were looking for but this thread is almost a year old now so maybe it will be helpful for someone in the future.